# SQL query in WHERE arabic condition

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle

when i write database query :

```
select * from mytable WHERE subTitle='داتا باللغه العربيه';
```

it not return any thing but it is found in database table

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please remove the inappropriate tag. What are your NLS settings for Oracle (client and server)? What client code are you using? What datatype does that column have? Are you sure it is an exact match? ...

Comment: try to use `select * from mytable WHERE subTitle LIKE N'%داتا باللغه العربيه%' `  .

Answer (score 1):

Since you've included Java as a tag, I'll assume you're using JDBC for connecting to the database, in which case you should **never** be sending that particular string (SQL statement) to the database.

That is because that particular string implies string concatenation for building the SQL statement, as in:

```
String subtitle = "داتا باللغه العربيه";
String sql = "select * from mytable WHERE subTitle='" + subtitle + "'";
```

That is a very big no, no, because it leaves you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Instead, you should be using a `PreparedStatement` and use parameters markers:

```
String subtitle = "داتا باللغه العربيه";
String sql = "select * from mytable WHERE subTitle=?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, subtitle);
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        // use result set here
    }
}
```

If this doesn't fix the character set issues you have, try using `setNString` instead. The 'N' is actually what you likely should have used for the string literal too, as in `N'داتا باللغه العربيه'`, but don't use the string literal.

Comment: Even with `setNString` (notice the "N")?

Comment: i solve it
DriverManager.getConnection("my connection string"+"?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","root", "");

Comment: @SalahBenAtwa Answer your own question and accept that answer, so others can benefit from your solution. Be sure to point out that you're talking about a MySQL connection, since your `oracle` tag may otherwise be confusing.

Answer (score -1):

select * from mytable WHERE subTitle='داتا باللغه العربيه'

Comment: select * from mytable WHERE subTitle=N'داتا باللغه العربيه'